# Change input text border color without changing its height

Tags: html, css, border

Let's say I have a default text input without any CSS

```
<input type="text" />
```

I want to change its border color to red so I add an style

```
<input type="text" style="border-color:red" />
```

After that the border is red, but its size is 2px. If I change the border to 1px the height of the input will be smaller than a default one.

How can I change my border to 1px and assure that the true height of the input (including the border) is the same as an default one?

Comment: Add a pixel of padding?

Comment: @cHao Yes it will work. But the problem is that im not sure if the input 2px border-width is the same in all browsers.

Comment: So decide what you  *want* to be the same in all browsers, and set it.  :)  There's a reason why in a lot of cases, the first rules people write (or include) are ones to "reset" styles to a known, consistent state.

Answer (score 32):

use this, it won't effect height:

```
<input type="text" style="border:1px solid #ff0000" />
```

Comment: Yes it does affect height, at least with Firefox 72.0.1.  With the border style given the input box appears with much reduced height compared to what is shown without the style.

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
<input type="text"/>
```

It will display same in all cross browser like mozilla, chrome and internet explorer.

```
<style>
    input{
       border:2px solid #FF0000;
    }
</style>
```

**Dont add style inline because its not good practise, use class to add style for your input box.**

Comment: Love how you say "try this.... **Dont do this** ".  One might suggest if you feel it's bad practice, you not demonstrate it.  Particularly in answers people will be voting on.  :)

Comment: Oh how the tide has turned in the last seven years... You're a heathen if you _don't_ inline your CSS anymore!

Answer (score 3):

Set a transparent border and then change it:

```
.default{
border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.new{
border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This css solution worked for me:

```
input:active,
input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #red
}

input:active,
input:focus {
    padding: 2px solid #red /*for firefox and chrome*/
}

/* .ie is a class you would need to set at the html root level */
.ie input:active,
.ie input:focus {
    padding: 3px solid #red /* IE needs 1px extra padding*/
}
```

I understand it is not necessary on FF and Chrome, but IE needs it. And there are circumstances when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for.

```
$("input.address_field").on('click', function(){  
     $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
});
```

Comment: There's definitely no need to use jQuery for this.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in a similar situation:

```
input:focus { 
   outline-offset: -2px; // negative value to 'squeeze' it inside 
   outline-color: orangered; // new desired color
```

}